# PHP scandir to find video files and not include subdirectories

Tags: php

I am trying to scan a directory and find all of the files, but I do not want to list the sub-directories. So what I did so far was this:

```
$directory = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/videos');
$videos = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
foreach ($videos as $video){
    echo $video;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The output of this is:

- Video_10mb.mp4
- Video_20mb.mp4
- Video_5mb.mp4
- poster
- thumbs
- tmp

I only want to list the files not the sub-directories. Like this:

- Video_10mb.mp4
- Video_20mb.mp4
- Video_5mb.mp4

How do I only show the video files?

Comment: scandir just returns filenames, and directories ARE just filenames. if you want to filter non-files, you need to `stat` each of those names and figure out what kind of file it is. for explicitly checking only dirs, `is_dir($video)` will `stat()` internally for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way using [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to find all the files in the directory /path/to/your/directory with a `.mp4` file extension:

```
foreach (glob("/path/to/your/directory/*.mp4") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

**See Example** :http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Thank you! With your answer I was able to figure out what I needed to do.